# VBA: Deleting particular columns in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working on a project and I need a program that will delete the empty columns (other than the header) in columns A through F and column J.  I'd like it to loop through `Range("A10:F10000")` and `Range("J:J")` and delete the columns from cell A10, B10, etc and down, then shift the remaining data left.  I was working with this, that affects the whole worksheet instead of just a range:

```
ecl = Sheet1.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Column

For cl = ecl To 1 Step -1
    cnt = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheet1.Columns(cl))
    If cnt = 1 Then
        Sheet1.Columns(cl).Delete
    End If

Next
```

I usually can use formulas and am not super familiar with VBA, but for this project it has to be a macro.  I hope this makes sense and would appreciate any advise!

Comment: Instead of columns specify a range in the CountA formula.

Comment: I'm confused about the goal of this program. You said you want to "delete columns from cell A10, B10, ect", so do you mean you want to delete cells starting from cell 10 in columns A-F and J? What do you mean by "shift the remaining data left" when you have specified that you don't want to delete the entire column? Seems like you're contradicting yourself in your explanation of your goal.

Comment: @jcrizk i get the impression that a few of the times that they say 'column' they actually mean 'cell'

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 I was thinking the same thing, but I would like clarification from the OP before I attempt to answer the question.

Comment: @jcrizk definitely. i was asking myself the same questions when i went through it and opted not to attempt

Comment: From your description this is what you are asking for... `Range("A10:F100000,J10:J10000").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft`

Comment: Yes, sorry I meant to say cells from A10, B10, etc, then shift the data to the left.

Answer (score 1):

you could use this:

```
Dim cl As Range, colsToDelete As Range
With ActiveSheet 'reference wanted sheet
    Set colsToDelete = .UsedRange.Columns(.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Offset(, 1).Resize(1, 1) ' initialize 'colsToDelete' to a "dummy" range certainly out of relevant one
    With Intersect(.Range("A10:J" & .UsedRange.Rows(.UsedRange.Rows.Count).Row), .Range("A:F, J:J")) ' reference referenced sheet range in column A to F and G form row 10 down to referenced sheet last not empty cell row
        For Each cl In .Columns ' lop through referenced range columns
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(cl) = 1 Then Set colsToDelete = Union(colsToDelete, cl) 'if current column is empty (i.e. only header in row 10) then add it to the colsToDelete range
        Next
        Set colsToDelete = Intersect(colsToDelete, .Cells) ' get rid of the "dummmy" range
    End With
End With
If Not colsToDelete Is Nothing Then colsToDelete.EntireColumn.Delete ' if any range to delete, do it!
```

Comment: @erokt51, any feedback?